# Opening a page on specific div

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I use vuejs and nuxt.

When using mysite.com/page1#section1, I would like to go to page1 with a focus on section1.
In my code I have :
`<div id="section1">...</div>`

But this doesn't work for a new page. When I am on the page mysite.com/page1 and I add #section1 to the url, it works.

So, how to I make the anchor works when I'm openning a new page? Should I add something in the router?

Comment: did you defined the routes?

Comment: Yes, in nuxt.config.js. The route works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use link like this:

```
<a href="http://youpage.com/child#section1">go to section 1 in child page</a>
```

And in child use:

```
<div id="section1"></div>
```

W3C spec about anchor links: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: If I use a <a> element the it works. But when opening the link mysite.com/page1#section1 from another site, I'm redirected to page1 but with no focus on section1.

Comment: I am afraid this is due to the way the single page applications are built. You would need to check in `created` lifehook if fragment is present and if so navigate to it using e.g. `document.getElementById('section1').scrollIntoView()`; or remove and add fragment again.

Comment: When I check document.getElementById('section1'), it's null. But I can actually see the div with id section1 when I browse "document". I thought getElementById could return a nested element but it's not the case here

Comment: @Raikyn you should use `mounted` lifehook.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue route you can easily make this:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
 let routes = [
     {path: '/',component: require('./components/index.vue').default},
     {path: '/about',component: require('./components/about.vue').default},
 ]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this :

```
<a href="#section1">home</a>
```

above will be click from which you have to got a specefic div on page.

```
<div id="section1"></div>
```

and this is div where you want to go on the page.

**Edit:** above example works if you have to go to a specific div **on the same page.**

else if you want to go to a div of any other page, in **href use website page address and then #id**

Comment: I would like to focus on anchor when opening a new page. The link to this anchor isn't in the same page.

Comment: @Raikyn this example should works the same way. You link to another page `https://my.link#my-section` and in the new page you need to have a section with `id#my-section`.

Comment: @LionelT Yes it should work but for some reason it doesn't. The html element (a div) is present with a id="section1".

Comment: Neither of these answers address the question.

Comment: @ChrisPink you have to use the both together. Id div is where the link after clicking will go and href is the click on which it should go to ID div